# D3 generated linearGradient not working in Firefox/IE

Tags: css, angularjs, firefox, svg, d3.js

I'm working on a D3 library that integrates D3 with AngularJS directives called [AngularD3](https://github.com/wealthbar/angular-d3). One of the recent directives allows gradients to be generated that can be bound to data and update dynamically. This seems to work on every browser except Firefox. However, if I copy/paste the output SVG into something like JSFiddle it works, so statically it's fine.

Could this be a limitation/bug with Firefox handling dynamic updates to the SVG?

Here is a demo page where you can see this working in Chrome and Safari but not in Firefox:

https://wealthbar.github.io/angular-d3/

This code is available via [the Github repository](https://github.com/wealthbar/angular-d3).

D3 is able to create gradients that do work with Firefox using largely the same code. You can see this in [Mike's example here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1086421). The only difference I can find so far is the dynamic updates to the linearGradient.

Here is the `<defs>` section of the SVG copied directly from Firefox using "copy outer html" in the DOM explorer for reference (formatted for readability):

```
<defs>
  <linearGradient y2="100%" y1="0%" x2="100%" x1="0%" id="gradient">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#098aae" stop-opacity="0.6"></stop>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#684684" stop-opacity="0.9"></stop>
  </linearGradient>
</defs>
```

Recently tested this in IE 10 and 11 and those do not work either.

Comment: Looks like this is a bug with angular-d3

Comment: You are creating an element named lineargradient rather than linearGradient. Since SVG is case sensitive, Firefox is the only thing that **doesn't** have a bug here.

Comment: I did notice that, but I don't believe that to be the issue. You can see the same in [this D3 example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1086421) which does work with Firefox. It seems to be just the way the DOM explorer displays the element. If you edit the HTML it is capitalized correctly. The snark is also completely uncalled for.

Comment: @itcouldevenbeaboat it could be though Firefox is the only browser I can find with the issue. Any particular reason why you think this issue is with D3?

Comment: In http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1086421 the linearGradient element is created with the correct case. That's why it's working. There's no snark in my previous comment. Chrome, Safari and presumably angular-d3 all suffer from bugs which are demonstrated in your question while Firefox does not.

Comment: Robert my code is essentially the same as Mikes it isn't going to produce different output. Further, neither example has case problem. The browser's (Firefox) DOM explorer just seems to lowercase the element when displaying it, both examples demonstrate this. However, if you click to edit the node you will see it is correctly cased. I've added the code directly from the "copy outer HTML" feature in Firefox to my question if that helps at all.

Comment: Try re-arranging things so that your `<defs>` element (and therefore your gradients is higher up in the DOM than the graphics that use the gradients.  I know older versions of some browsers had a problem with things in the wrong order (even in static markup), it's possible that Firefox still has a problem with dynamic markup.

Comment: Thanks, I had thought of that and did try that out but the result is the same. I can post a demo of that as well if that's worthwhile though. Also since the static version works I'm still suspecting it's something to do with D3 dynamically setting the values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here:

1. You seem to have **multiple elements in the document with the same ID**; your `<d3-gradient>` element has an ID of `gradient` too.  I'm surprised Chrome still works despite this.
2. I think the main issue here is that your external stylesheet contains `url(#gradient)`.  Firefox interprets this as being **relative to the stylesheet**, rather than relative to the document.  I'm not sure why Chrome still works in this scenario, but perhaps it falls back to expanding it relative to the document.

You can read a bit more about [Firefox's handling of partial URLs](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=632004).  I believe it is interpreting the specification correctly, while WebKit isn't.

As for the fix, I tried `url(../#gradient)`, but this worked in Firefox and not Chrome/WebKit.  You could use an inline `style="url(#gradient)"` instead.

Comment: Other browsers = webkit or things that once were webkit. IE9+ works the same as Firefox FWIW.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the answer to make the "correctness" note clearer.

Comment: Thanks so much, it was a combination of the two. Ensure there wasn't a duplicate id *and* changing the style to `fill: url(/#gradient)`. The slash works fine in both Firefox and Chrome. I still have to test IE.

Comment: So in an interesting result it seems that Firefox understand `url(/#gradient)` or `url(..#gradient)` and even `url(../#gradient)` while IE only seems to understand `url(#gradient)`. Webkit seems to accept any form.

Comment: "You could use an inline style="url(#gradient)" instead", save my day!

Comment: I've also found the following format (discovered in desperation) to work perfectly well in Firefox: `.attr("style", "fill:url(#gradient)")`. Strangely, I've yet to see it documented elsewhere.