# Clip path is not working with svg and d3

Tags: d3.js, svg, clip-path

I am trying to make a scatter plot with. Zooming seems to work but the dots spreading off the axis is something that I don't want. I have Googled for a while and could not solve my problem. I have already tried the solution posted in this post but it did not work: [Svg clip-path within rectangle does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486896/svg-clip-path-within-rectangle-does-not-work)

Please find my code here: https://github.com/e-kaya/scatter

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to add a [mcve] to the question itself. Asking people to download your entire github project is not going to get you any answers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the reference, @Mark. I had to reverse-transform the clip-board element.

Comment: @Robert, I tried my best to make my code as minimal as possible. The entire github project was composed of a plain implementation of scatter plot and 50 rows of data. I thought it would be better than putting all that into a single post.