# how to get rid of overlap line graph in d3js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

can you please help me to remove the overlap line on my line graph. This is a dynamic graph. So whenever I want to change the scale of my graph to a bigger domain, the whole path should be there. and when i change again the scale to smaller one, I dont want to see the line graph or just see the lines that covers the range of my scale. thanks.

```
var data = [
    {"x":1, "y":1},
    ....
    ....
    ];

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.y); });


var path = svg.append("path")
    .data([data])
    .attr("d", line)
    .attr("stroke", "black");
```

click the link for sample output.

from: [CLICK HERE FOR SAMPLE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLKV4.jpg)

to: [CLICK HERE FOR SAMPLE OUTPUT IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JuRQ.jpg)

Comment: clip it with a clipPath

Comment: thank you for the idea but how can i retain the line inside the graph?

Comment: That would be inside the clipPath.

Comment: got it! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, use clip path. Here are a few examples that will help :

http://www.d3noob.org/2015/07/clipped-paths-in-d3js-aka-clippath.html

[Svg clip-path within rectangle does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486896/svg-clip-path-within-rectangle-does-not-work)

http://bl.ocks.org/couchand/6399221

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath